# could't parse tht android application modules gradles config

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, connection

**project module**

And I really can't solve it.

I've seen quite a lot of people getting this error, everyone saying remove jcenter but in my case there is no jcenter i found

have tried everything available in internet but can't resolve this problem
plz someone fix this problem

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

**app module**
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firstapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your JUnit dependency is missing a version.

Please try replacing:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
```

with:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
```